# Solving recurrent sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have recently learned that recurrence relations can be solved can be solved using generating functions. I wonder what sequences can actually be solved using this method with examples (excluding trivial cases such as $x_n = Ax_{n-1} + Bx_{n-2}$) and what other methods exist for more complex cases.

Comment: Lots of sequences can be. It just depends on your ability to manipulate the generating function. E.g. in your example, $ f(x) - x_0 - x_1 x = A (f(x) - x_0) + Bf(x)$. Can you find $f(x)$?

Comment: @Calvin, what does this relation mean exactly?